# ng2-bootstrap datepicker error

Tags: ng2-bootstrap, ng2-datepicker

I am implementing ng2-bootstrap datePicker in my angular 2 app but faced some type of modules error and I do not understand what is the problem behind.Please help me.

**module.ts**

```
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/datepicker';
@NgModule({
 imports: [
 ...........  
 DatepickerModule
 ...........
 ],
 declarations: [
 .....
 .....
]})

export class Modules {
 }
```

**html**

```
<datepicker></datepicker>
```

**error**

```
 'datepicker' is not a known element:
    1. If 'datepicker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'datepicker' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("<div class="form-group"><div>
                          [ERROR ->]<datepicker></datepicker>
                          <!--<datepicker [expanded]="true" class="danger"-"): AddCustomer@49:26
    Can't bind to 'expanded' since it isn't a known property of 'datepicker'. ("                              <div>
                                                    <datepicker [ERROR ->][expanded]="true" class="danger"
                                                                form"): AddCustomer@212:64
    'datepicker' is not a known element:
```

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your import, try this  DatepickerModule.forRoot()